# Basis of a vector space and subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

It is given that basis ***B*** = { v1 ,...,*vn*} for a vector space ***V*** and ***U*** a subspace of ***V***, then there ***C*** be a subset of ***B*** that is a basis for ***U***.
Would this be true? Struggling to wrap my mind around this. A proof/counterexample would help immensely.

Comment: Consider the standard basis $B$ for $\mathbb{R}^n = V$. The subsets of this basis give you things like "flat" lines and planes and coordinate hyperplanes but will not give you other subspaces. e.g. there is no subset of $B = \{(1,0), (0,1)\}$ that is a basis for $U = \{(x,x): x \in \mathbb{R}^2\}$ although $B$ is a basis for $V = \mathbb{R}^2$ and $U$ is a subspace of $V$. There are some details to check here.

Comment: It's certainly true that any subspace of $V$ will have a basis that can be extended to a basis of $V$ (this is clearest in finite dimensions). But it is not generally true that the set of subspaces of $V$ is the set of spans of subsets of a *given, fixed* basis of $V$. For example this would imply that any finite-dimensional vector space has only a finite number of subspaces, which is obviously false (see above, lines through the origin in $\mathbb{R}^2$).

Comment: Sorry, I wrote my first comment wrong. I meant to write: I think it is true that for any subspace **U** of **V**,  *there exists* a basis **B** of the vector space **V** such that there is a subset of **B** which is a basis of **U**. Is this correct? And sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @AdamRubinson definitely. It seems like the question is about a kind of attempted reversal of that with a fixed basis. It may not be clear. Will keep an eye on edits to see if that's where it's going.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Given a basis ***B*** $= \{ v_1 ,...,v_n\}$ of a vector space ***V***, and a subspace ***U*** of ***V***, then there is *not necessarily* a subset **C** of ***B*** such that **C** is a basis for ***U***.

leslie townes gives a standard example in the comments: There is no subset of **B** = $\{(0,1),(1,0)\}$ which is a basis of **U** = $\{(x,x): x \in \mathbb{R}^2 \},\ $ yet **U** is a subspace of **V** = span(**B**) $= \mathbb{R^2}.$

What *is* true that for any subspace **U** of **V**,  *there exists* a basis **B** of the vector space **V** such that there is a subset of **B** which is a basis of **U**. Notice in *this* statement, you are not given the basis (of **V**), you can *choose* the basis - and you have a wide choice - to be one that conveniently has a subset that is a basis of **U**.